# Remove all the whitespace after ',' and make first letter uppercase in CSV with PHP

Tags: php, csv, whitespace, capitalize, uppercase

I'm having a CSV like this.

```
john,joy, anna, Lucy Bravo,boy
```

I want to remove whitespace after ',' if it exist. And also make the first letter after ',' to be capital letter, if its not capital already. That is it should be like this:

```
John,Joy,Anna,Lucy Bravo,Boy
```

Only the whitespace after the ',' should go. I tried myself. But all failed. I hope PHP can solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`trim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) and [`ucfirst()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php).

Here's a modified example from the documentation:

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo ucfirst(trim($data[$c])) . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use regular expressions, but it's probably easiest to split it up into an array and operate on each entry:

```
function fix_entry($str) {
    return ucfirst(ltrim($str));
}

$str = 'john,joy, anna, Lucy bravo,boy';
$fixed = implode(',', array_map(fix_entry, explode(',', $str)));
```

If you're opposed to making a function you could just use two `array_map`s, but that's up to you

Answer (score 2):

Use str_getcsv to break the line into an array. Loop the array and use trim() or ltrim() and ucfirst() on each value.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php